# get video id from youtube playlist in as3

Tags: youtube, playlist, actionscript-3

How to get video id from youtube playlist in as3, in order to play latest uploaded video from you tube playlist.

I have load pLay List and it plays properly but I want to play only latest video from play list.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) to fetch information about the items in a playlist.

In order to be able to use the API, you need to generate an API key. [Info about how to do so can be found here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).

To get the latest video in a certain playlist you can make a GET request for this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId={YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Let's break it down to see what it does:

- **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems** - *This is the URL endpoint to request data about [playlist items in the Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)*
- **?part=contentDetails** - *We define what details we want returned from the query. In this case we want the video id's, so we use `contentDetails`*
- **&maxResults=1** - *We are only interested in one item - the latest. (It appears that the result is ordered from latest to oldest, so by only requesting the first video it should return the latest.)*
- **&playlistId={YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID}** - *Replace this value with the ID of the playlist in question.*
- **&key={YOUR_API_KEY}** - *Replace this value with your API key.*

Let's look at a sample request:

```
var playlistUrl:String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=PL4Sz7_l-PtwAG8xye4Y9whykc4OAwbN9f&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"
var playlistReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(playlistUrl);
var playlistLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
playlistLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handlePlaylistUrlLoaded);
playlistLoader.load(playlistReq);

function handlePlaylistUrlLoaded(e:Event):void {
    trace(playlistLoader.data); // See the response below
    var playlistResponse:Object = JSON.parse(playlistLoader.data); // Parse the JSON response
    trace(playlistResponse.items[0].contentDetails.videoId); // Prints "21Ox58OKFmo" which is the video id of the latest video in this playlist
}
```

The raw response to this sample query is:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "\"FOuwADrXJjsTKgUIQJoQC6nKNFY/n3kL7MtTJyPOfHU6jmro9gAC1CI\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 189,
         "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"FOuwADrXJjsTKgUIQJoQC6nKNFY/aNpryIHyioAUu4C9_WVP8kZGbuE\"",
            "id": "PL88DYY_1F2muJ4Dv0iAFHEuKQuma2y_BH0WbF7AzESJw",
            "contentDetails": {
                "videoId": "21Ox58OKFmo"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Edit in response to further details

If you want to use the YouTube player API, it seems like you have to wait for a "video cued" event after adding the playlist to the cue.

So, in essence, this should work (untested code):

```
youtubePlayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
youtubePlayer.cuePlaylist("{YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID}");

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
    if (Object(event).data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
        // Playlist cued, the playlist data should now be accessible
        var playlist:Array = youtubePlayer.getPlaylist();
        trace(playlist[0]); // This value should now exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi walkietokyo, thank you for answer, I have put a comment in my answer above. Thank you one more time

Comment: @user3799338 You should amend *your original question* to provide further details rather than to post a separate answer. Anyway, I have amended my answer with some details on when the playlist should be available using the Youtube Player API.

Comment: sorry for mistakes I am new user.

Comment: Your code works but when I want to play video with ID that I get from your code it plays with TypeError: "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object", I guess because I put youTubeplayer.cueVideoById(playlist[0],0); in function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void. Should I removeEventListener onStateChange after play video?

Comment: @user3799338 Check if `playlist` is null. The Youtube Player API led me to believe that the `getPlaylist();` would return a value once the "video cued" event was triggered, but I'm not 100% sure... You could also try replacing `YT.PlayerState.CUED` with the number `5` (means the same thing, only that the former is easier to read. If, however, the `YT.PlayerState` isn't available, it could give an error like the one you see.)